# How can I use ng-model two-way binding with a function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, model

So, I was coming up with this great data model approach for my Angular app which lets me do fancy stuff like this:

```
var product = productModel.create();
product.set('name', 'Widget');
product.set('price', 12.99);
product.set('quantity', 46);
product.save().success(function() {
    alert('It saved!');
});
```

But then I realized...this doesn't work with ng-model :(

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="product.get('name')" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="product.get('quantity')" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="product.get('price')" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

When I type text in an input field, I get this

> Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'product.get('name')' is
>   non-assignable. Element: `<input type="text" ng-model="product.get('name')" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">`

Obviously this happens because Angular wants to bind against a variable, but instead I'm trying to bind against a function call.

I really would like to keep this model approach that uses get() and set(). How can I make this work with ng-model and still have two-way binding? There must be a way...

Comment: The closest that you could get to is to bind to [getter/setter](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel&sa=U&ei=MTBUVOa-J4mOoQS_voHwDA&ved=0CAsQFjAA&sig2=okwgvGv0NVwdBKXWtyn-pg&usg=AFQjCNHHBagckK1itUwiGZSfTvb2G_MklA), but that would still require you to change your function signatures

Comment: See [Binding to a getter/setter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) section at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//when creating the {get: ..., set: ...} object, also add this method:
product.bind = function(key) {
  var obj = this
  return function(val) {
    if (angular.isDefined(val)) {
      obj.set(key, val)
    }
    return obj.get(key)
  }
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
<form ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}">
  <input ng-model="product.bind('name')">
</form>
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/1GyWhswyO43R6nm49hHP?p=preview

Comment: Oh wow dude, that's awesome. You deserve many points for this. This is exactly what I was looking for. Returning a function inside of a function is brilliant.

Comment: One thing I found is: It's probably a good idea to set `allowInvalid` to true in `ng-model-options` for forms that use bind. Otherwise, text fields will not update with every kestroke if every keystroke results in a valid model value -- particularly if you are using ng-pattern  validations in your forms. I'm using: `ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true, allowInvalid: true}"`.